# Javascript causes select input to get stuck

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, dom

I have a JavaScript function that refreshes the options contained within a select based on a category and sub-category system. These selects were generated by a php function based on the contents of a mssql database.

To consult the hierarchy of categories i have stored this information into a 2 dimensional array using php, then passed this array to JavaScript using json_encode.

My function works as it is supposed to, however when the user wishes to change the value in a select, they cannot! they can only see the available options but not choose one.

here is my JavaScript function:

```
function refresh_values() {
    //the dropdown_array is my array conatining the heirarchy information

    var options = "<option value=\"Tous\">Tous</option>"; //default "All" choice
    var dup_array = new Array();                          //to prevent doubles

    if (document.getElementById('bloc').value != 'Tous') {

        for (var i = 0; i <dropdown_array.length; i++) {
            if (dropdown_array[i][0] == document.getElementById('bloc').value && !(dropdown_array[i][2] == null) && !(contains(dup_array, dropdown_array[i][2]))) {
                dup_array.push(dropdown_array[i][2]);
                options += "<option value=\"" + dropdown_array[i][2] + "\">" + dropdown_array[i][2] + "</option>";
            }
        }
    }else {
        for (var i = 0; i <dropdown_array.length; i++) {
            if (!contains(dup_array, dropdown_array[i][2])) {
                dup_array.push(dropdown_array[i][2]);
                options += "<option value=\"" + dropdown_array[i][2] + "\">" + dropdown_array[i][2] + "</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('processus').innerHTML = options;

    if (document.getElementById('processus').value != 'Tous') {

        for (var i = 0; i <dropdown_array.length; i++) {
            if (dropdown_array[i][2] == document.getElementById('activite').value && !(dropdown_array[i][4] == null) && (!contains(dup_array, dropdown_array[i][4]))) {
                dup_array.push(dropdown_array[i][4]);
                options += "<option value=\"" + dropdown_array[i][4] + "\">" + dropdown_array[i][4] + "</option>";
            }
        }
    }else {
        for (var i = 0; i <dropdown_array.length; i++) {
            if (!contains(dup_array, dropdown_array[i][4])) {
                dup_array.push(dropdown_array[i][4]);
                options += "<option value=\"" + dropdown_array[i][4] + "\">" + dropdown_array[i][4] + "</option>";
            }
        }        
    }
    document.getElementById('activite').innerHTML = options;
}
```

Here is my "contains" function:

```
function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the html/php that "builds" the selects

```
<!--The script after each input is to preserve it's value after the form is submitted
I've already identified this as being irrelevant to my problem via testing-->

<form id="search" method="GET">
    <span class="form_label">Numero: </span>
    <input type="text" name="numero" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['numero']) ? $_GET['numero'] : '' ?>"/>
    <br>

    <span class="form_label">Bloc processus: </span>
    <?php echo generate_dropdown("table_name", "nom_bloc_francais", "bloc");?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('bloc').value = "<?php echo $_GET['bloc'];?>";
    </script>
    <br>

    <span class="form_label">Processus: </span>
    <?php echo generate_dropdown("table_name", "nom_processus_francais", "processus");?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('processus').value = "<?php echo $_GET['processus'];?>";
    </script>
    <br>

    <span class="form_label">Activite: </span>
    <?php echo generate_dropdown("table_name", "nom_activite_francais", "activite");?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('activite').value = "<?php echo $_GET['activite'];?>";
    </script>
    <input type="submit" value="Search!"/>
</form>
```

This is the php function that generates the selects initially:

```
function generate_dropdown($table, $field, $name) {
        $options = "<option value=\"Tous\">Tous</option>";
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT " . $field . " FROM " . $table. " ";

        $filter=mssql_query($query);
        while($row = mssql_fetch_array($filter)) {
            $options .= "<option value=\"". $row[$field] . "\">" . $row[$field] . "</option>";
        }

        $menu='
            <select name="' . $name . '" class="filter" id="' . $name . '" onchange="refresh_values()">
              ' . $options . '
            </select>';

        return $menu;
}
```

Can anyone please at least point me in the right direction as to the reason why the user cannot change the value of the select from "Tous"?

More Info:
When i remove the JavaScript function the selects' values can be changed.

Thank you

Comment: Not so sure (quite a lot of code in the example), but are you really sure you want to do the refresh of the values in the **onchange** event? This gets run every time someone makes a selection in the dropdown, which means it will refresh the list of options whenever that happens.

It sounds more like you want to put this code in a $(document).ready() handler or similar, i.e. make it run after the page is completely loaded.

Comment: Yes! this is the purpose of the function, i need to refresh the list of options so that it is dynamic, at "run-time", without the need for a reload. Sorry for all the code btw, there is certainly too much, but i feel too mcuh information is better than not enough

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but when I read your code now I see that you have the refresh-method being called when both of your dropdowns are changed - and it in turns modifies the `processus` element. Is this correct? It sounds, in my eyes, at least a bit strange. :) Anyway, I have another idea, will post it as an answer to see if it works.

Comment: Nah, I don't think my idea will work. Was thinking if onchanged is cancelable or anything to the like, but... that's probably a false start from my end.

Comment: It occurs to me that we don't really know what you mean by 'cannot change'. If you mean that when the user selects a new value the dropdown resets to the default then it's pretty obvious that somewhere in your code you are overriding the default behaviour. I would strip out enough code so that the selection works and then add it back in piece by piece....

Comment: Here's what happens, the select opens up to show all the options, when the user clicks on one of the options, the select controls value remains at the previous option ("Tous"). I haven't overridden any defaults that i know of, but i will check, any pointers on where to look?

Comment: Check if the control works as expected if you remove the onchange event:  onchange="refresh_values()"

Comment: Yes the select works as expected when i remove the onchange event

Comment: Well I would guess that your onChange event is rebuilding the dropdown and therefore wiping out any selection made. Try commenting out; 
document.getElementById('activite').innerHTML = options;

Do you need to rebuild the dropdown?? If so you will need to store the selected Index or value before you rebuild the dropdown and then manually set it back again afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. After extensive debugging, i realized that this function is being called every time i change a select's value. This means that no matter what select i choose to change, it will regenerate it. So when i change it, the select is rebuilt and the value is set back to the default.

The fix was to simply add a parameter to the function to define which select is being changed.

Comment: Glad you managed to find it. I think there are also other areas of improvement of your code; for example, the code that generates the option(s) could perhaps be split out into a helper function. I'm quite sure you could reduce the code size (and therefore the complexity involved in maintaining) substantially by following quite simple steps. This is basically [this hint](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the innerHTML property is not a great way to build a Select control. Try building the control dynamically within your loop that generates the innerHTML.

```
var drpDown= document.getElementById('activite');
var newOp = document.createElement("option");
newOp.text = "Txt";
newOp.value = "1";
drpDown.options.add(newOp);
```

Comment: You're right about that. But will it really solve the original problem? :) (of course, it might be a good step in the right direction, because as we all know, clean code which does things in the proper way usually works better, but still...)

Comment: Well, I was wondering if you were using IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557619/adding-option-elements-using-innerhtml-in-ie

Comment: Incredibly good point, mate! I'm not the original poster so I have no idea, but hopefully, this could be a lead...

Comment: Well, i would like it to work on IE, but i'm doing most of my testing on chrome. working on implementing your solution now.

Comment: I've implemented this solution, but it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks anyways