# Why isn't my AJAX request getting the correct value from a drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a web application that will utilize a triple dependent drop-down menu (think country->state->city) and allow users to change their details.

Here is a code snippet of the drop-down structure (note that the value of the default option of `dropAccounts` is `'test'`):

```
        //create a drop down of available accounts
        echo 'Available Accounts: ';

        echo '<select name="dropAccounts" class="dropAccounts">';
        //if there is at least one account available
        if (count($accsAvailable) > 0) {
            echo '<option value="test">---Select an account---</option>'; //default option
            foreach ($accsAvailable as $account) {
                //populate from API
                echo '<option value=' . $account->getId(). '>' . $account->getName() . '</option>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option value="0">---No accounts available---</option>'; //else if no accounts exist
        }
        echo '</select>';

        //for available webproperties
        echo '<br> Available Webproperties: ';
        echo '<select name="dropProperties" class="dropProperties" id="dropProperties">';
        echo '<option selected="selected">---Select a webproperty---</option>';
        echo '</select>';

        //for available profiles
        echo '<br> Available Profiles: ';
        echo '<select name="dropProfiles" class="dropProfiles" id="dropProfiles">';
        echo '<option selected="selected">---Select a profile---</option>';
        echo '</select>';
```

I am using an `onchange` event and AJAX to extract the value from the first drop-down menu, `dropAccounts` (country), and using that value to index an API call to populate the second drop-down menu, `dropProperties` (state) as such:

```
$(".dropAccounts").change(function()
{
       var accountID = $(".dropAccounts").val(); //gets the account ID from drop-down value
       populateProperties(accountID);
});

function populateProperties(accountID) {
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "propertyID.php",
                    data: {
                        'accountID' : accountID
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $(".dropProperties").html(html);

                        // Populate profiles after properties load
                        populateProfiles($(".dropProperties").val());
                    } 
                });
            }
```

The AJAX request replaces the contents of the `dropProperties` (state) drop-down and then calls the `populateProfiles()` function to populate the final drop-down, `dropProfiles` (city) in a similar fashion:

```
        function populateProfiles(propertyID) {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "profileID.php",
                data: {
                    'propertyID' : propertyID
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $(".dropProfiles").html(html);
                } 
            });
        }
```

This method works properly to populate the first two dropdowns with the correct, `dropAccounts` (country) and `dropProperties`, however the value retrieved in the third drop-down `dropProfiles` (city) is not the value from `dropProperties`.

In the **profileID.php** script:

```
<?php
$propertyID = $_POST['propertyID'];
echo '<option> Property ID: ' . $propertyID . '</option>';
?>
```

The value for `$propertyID` is returning as `'test'` from the default option of `dropAccounts`. I have double-checked all variables, and I am stumped. I was wondering if someone with more experienced eyes could pick out the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know that [IE doesn't like `innerHTML` on `<select>` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557619/adding-option-elements-using-innerhtml-in-ie?rq=1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is you are using a class selector meaning you could potentially be having more than one elements returned, in which case, I'm not sure how `.val()` would work on a set of elements.

You also should get the value by getting the value of the selected option.

Try using it like so...

`var accountID = $(".dropAccounts").first().find('option:selected').val();`

### Edit

We need a better way to select the element you are attempting to get the value for so I think your best bet is to modify the element with something we can use to select it and be sure that nothing else is going to get in the way.

Modify this line `echo '<select name="dropAccounts" class="dropAccounts">';`

I'd suggest adding an ID which would be unique on this page so we can accurately use jQuery to be sure we are only selecting this element.

`echo '<select name="dropAccounts" class="dropAccounts" id='someuniqueid'>';`

Then with jQuery, it will be much easier to grab the value...

`var accountID = $("#someuniqueid > option:selected").val()`  // syntax error fixed

So basically what this is saying is telling jQuery to get the element whose ID is `someuniqueid` which is your select element, then it's going to grab the `selected option` of that select element.

Comment: Thanks for replying! No luck with this, `$_POST['propertyID']` is still `'test'`.

Comment: Getting closer with your update! Still not returning the right value though. The value for `$_POST['propertyID']` is returning is `---Select a webproperty---`, presumably from the default option for `dropProperties`. Is there a way to grab new value being populated?

Comment: Sorry for the very long delay, I usually don't check this during the weekend.  The `option:selected` portion should have selected the selected option.  Try `alert($(".dropAccounts").length)`.  That will tell you the number of elements that this selector is matching.  If it's more than one, then we need to select this option another way, probably by adding an id to it and selecting the id.

Comment: No worries! Everybody has weekends, hope you had a good one! I just checked the length of `dropProperties` (the drop-down we are trying to get the value from) and its returning with 3 elements.

Comment: Okay, that would explain why its coming up with a value.  So what's happening is `$(".dropAccounts")` is actually selecting 3 different elements on your page which means we need to come up with a way to select only the one you want to get the value for.  I was just assuming we wanted the first element which is why we used `first()`.  I'll update my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for the swift replies. I am getting a syntax error with that line, my apologies, I am new to JS so I can't pick out the error. My line is `var selected = $("#dropProperties" > option:selected).val();`

Comment: Sorry rookie mistake, Updated again.

Comment: I think you might have solved my problem! I made the changes and the drop-down doesn't update, but checking its value in the debugger it's correctly grabbing the correct value from the right drop-down. Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to set the value of the dropdown, use the exact same syntax except you supply the value as an argument. `$("#dropProperties" > option:selected).val(somevalue);`

Comment: I'm still having issues setting the value of the drop-down, but I think I can find a way to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Options have two parts, the value and the display name.  You're only setting the display name.

```
<?php
$propertyID = $_POST['propertyID'];
echo "<option value='" . $propertyID . "'> Property ID: " . $propertyID . '</option>';
?>
```

Also making your blank options selected by default is not a good idea since you probably want to set the selected option via the Ajax call, right?  In fact, why not have the Ajax return the whole dropdown (all options) again with the proper value selected rather than only return one option?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No luck. The value of `$_POST['propertyID']` is `'test'`

Comment: Because you didn't change it, or you made the mistake of giving every option a value of test.  View the source in browser.  Also you should probably give your `select` tags an id and use `$("#dropAccounts")` to select by ID rather than by class, even though I doubt that has anything to do with it. Its just cleaner.